# Toggle relationship in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to implement follow/unfollow in Neo4J. I would like to write a query would toggle the relationship between two nodes.

I currently have the following query:

```js
neoSession.writeTransaction(tx => tx.run('MATCH (me:User), (other:User) WHERE ID(me) = $me AND ID(other) = $other OPTIONAL MATCH (me)-[af:FOLLOWS]->(other) CALL apoc.do.when(af IS NULL, CREATE (me)-[f:FOLLOWS]->(other), DELETE af)', { me: req.user_id, other: req.body.user, datetime: Date.now() }));
```

Prettified query-only:

```
MATCH (me:User), (other:User) 
  WHERE ID(me) = $me AND ID(other) = $other 
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)-[af:FOLLOWS]->(other) 
CALL 
  apoc.do.when(
    af IS NULL, 
    CREATE (me)-[f:FOLLOWS]->(other), 
    DELETE af
  )
```

But this results in the error

```
Neo4jError: Invalid input '>' (line 1, column 169 (offset: 168))

"MATCH (me:User), (other:User) WHERE ID(me) = $me AND ID(other) = $other OPTIONAL MATCH (me)-[af:FOLLOWS]->(other) CALL apoc.do.when(af IS NULL, CREATE (me)-[f:FOLLOWS]->(other), DELETE af)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queries (last two arguments) to `apoc.do.when()` have to be strings, so quote each of them.

Also, in order for each of those queries to use those variables, you need to pass those variables in a parameter map as a 4th argument.

Each of the conditional queries must RETURN something, otherwise there will be no rows yielded and anything after would be a no-op.

The call must `YIELD value`, so that needs to be present, and last, a query cannot end with a procedure call, so you need to RETURN something.

This one should work, you can adjust it as needed:

```
MATCH (me:User), (other:User) 
  WHERE ID(me) = $me AND ID(other) = $other 
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)-[af:FOLLOWS]->(other) 
CALL 
  apoc.do.when(
    af IS NULL, 
    "CREATE (me)-[f:FOLLOWS]->(other) RETURN f", 
    "DELETE af RETURN null as f",
    {me:me, af:af}
  ) YIELD value
RETURN value.f as f
```